# Flexbox: justify-content property in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, flexbox

I'm fixing my layout on Internet Explorer, using the official virtual machines downloadable [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/).

I'm currently using windows 7 with Internet Explorer 11. Unfortunately, my layout is not centred. This is how it's supposed to be:

```
 +--------------+
 |              |
 |   +------+   |
 |   |      |   |
 |   |      |   |
 |   +------+   |
 |              |
 +--------------+
```

And this is how I see it in IE11:

```
 +--------------+
 |              |
 |      +------+|
 |      |      ||
 |      |      ||
 |      +------+|
 |              |
 +--------------+
```

That's the code that I'm using to centre the modal:

background css:

```
  .modal {
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
      z-index: 100;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      flex-direction: row;
      justify-content: center;
      display: -ms-flexbox;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
```

centred box css:

```
  .box {
      background: $white;
      align-self: center;
      width: 550px;
      margin: auto;
      padding: $padding $padding 0 $padding;
      line-height: 1.4em;

      &--gray-background {
          background: $gray;
      }

      &--small {
          max-height: 720px;
      }

      &--big {
          max-height: 100%;
      }

      &--no-width {
          width: auto;
      }

      &--no-pad {
          padding: 0;
      }
  }
```

Here's the HTML:

```
....
<div class="modal">
    <div class="box box--no-pad">
    <!-- modal content -->
    </div>
</div>
```

I think the problem is "justify-content" because if I remove that property on IE works, but I can't understand why I have to do that: it should be supported by IE...

EDIT: if I change the property

```
flex-direction: row;
```

to

```
flex-direction: column;
```

in the modal css class, as suggested in the linked answer I obtain the following result:

```
 +--------------+
 |              |
 |              |
 |   +------+   |
 |   |      |   |
 |   |      |   |
 |   +------+   |
 +--------------+
```

The modal is centred horizontally now, but not vertically.

Comment: IE is not _bug free_ when it comes to Flexbox, so use auto margins on the flex item instead.

Comment: There might be situations you will need to use `transform: translate` to center items in IE (and Safari)

Comment: Btw, when you tried using `flex-direction: column`, did you also had `margin: auto` on the item?

Comment: Thanks @LGSon! That solved my problem!